# shell module: Bash <(process substitution) with ansible

Tags: shell, ansible

I want to run a command:

```
- name: install pip
  shell: "python <(curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)"
```

But achieve an error

```
failed: [default] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "python <(curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)", "delta": "0:00:00.002073", "end": "2014-12-03 15:52:01.780837", "rc": 2, "start": "2014-12-03 15:52:01.778764", "warnings": []}
stderr: /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I tried to change it to something like:

```
python <$(curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)
```

but it doesn't work. Any thoughts?

**NB:** this question about using `<` operator in shell module and I know that better to use `apt` for install something

Comment: `shell` is almost certainly using `/bin/sh` to run the command. `/bin/sh` does not support Process Substitution. Get it to use `bash` instead or you can try piping the curl output to python instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*EDIT: though this answers this the question I think mgsk's answer is a better answer since I agree that it's not the right way to go about it with Ansible.*

This should fix your issue:

```
- name: install pip
  shell: "python <(curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)" executable=/bin/bash
```

If you are wondering the difference between these two commands:

```
python <(curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)
python <$(curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)
```

The first one uses [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) which is a bash feature which is why you cannot use it with /bin/sh as your shell.  What it's doing is taking the output of the curl command (which is a python script), writing it to a temporary file and using that file as an argument to python which takes a python script as its first argument.

The second one is an ambiguous redirect because the python script that is generated from the curl is not a file

Answer (score 9):

Use `command` module if you actually do not need `shell`.

Also you will be better off using `get_url` module for downloading the file instead of relying on `curl` being installed on remote server.
Recent versions of Ansible will display a warning when you try to use `curl` instead of `get_url` module also:

`"warnings": ["Consider using get_url module rather than running curl"]`

Here is how I would do this:

```
- name: Download pip installer
  get_url:
    url=https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
    dest=/tmp/get-pip.py
    mode=0440

- name: Install pip
  command: /usr/bin/python /tmp/get-pip.py
```

For extra options to `get_url` module visit: http://docs.ansible.com/get_url_module.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass the args keyword to pass the executable:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html

Answer (score -1):

```
  - name: configure zookeeper /etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
    shell: "{{ item }}" 
    with_items:
       if [ -f /etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo_cfg.org ] ;
       then  cp /etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo_cfg.org  /etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg ;
       else cp /etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg /etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo_cfg.org;
       fi;
       cat /vagrant/zoo.cfg.j2 >> /etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg;
```

Comment: Please explain your solution.